# Can anyone suggest a way I can get my class="selected" to work on my navigation in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, navigation

Can anyone suggest a way I can get my class="selected" to work on my navigation in Wordpress?

I have a wordpress navigation setup:

If I am on the home page, my home page class is selected.

If I want to go to page one, I want this class to change in thenavigation so only this class loads and not the home page.

I use: class="selected" to activate my roll over effect.

I can get this to work on a fixed site, just not on wordpress, any suggestions here?

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Could I use an if statement here?

```
   <?php if(is_home() ) {

    //for example load class="selected"

    } else {

    //for example if other page don't load class="selected"

   } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you're using a hardcoded navigation, and not [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) from WordPress.

So, you can conditionally check for each page you are using:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li<?php echo is_home()? '  class="selected"'; '';?>>
    <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li<?php echo is_page('Contact')? '  class="selected"'; '';?>>
    <a href="#">Contact page</a>
  </li>
  <li<?php echo is_single('My first Post')? ' class="selected"'; '';?>>
    <a href="#">Myfirst post</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You should make use of the [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) present in WordPress.

If you look at the first `<li>` you will see `<?php echo is_home()? '  class="selected"'; '';?>` This code is expressed as a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) which is the equivalent of

```
if( is_home() ){
  echo ' class="selected"'; #echo class. white space in front so that it does not stick to the "<li"
else{
  echo ''; #do nothing
}
```

In the example above, I used three functions:

**[`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)** - Returns true if you are on the home page

**[`is_page($arg)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)** - Returns true if you are on the page specified by `$arg`.

**[`is_single($arg)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)** - Returns true if you are on the post specified by `$arg`.

There are other [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) available that you can choose to use.